# MySQL slave server from dumps

Tags: mysql-replication, mysql

I've created a slave server from live machine which is acting as a master now.
I use the following procedure to create it:

```
mysqldump --opt -Q -B --master-data=2 --all-databases > dump.sql
```

- then I imported this dump on the new machine, applied the "CHANGE MASTER TO..." directive with a log file/position from the dump.

Please note that I have around 8000 databases and I didn't stop the master while the dumps were running.

The replication works fine but is this a properly method for creating a slave server? I'm planning to promote this slave to a master (different location) so I would like to make sure that there is a 100% data consistency between the servers.

I've found [this](http://www.elevatedcode.com/articles/2008/03/02/creating-a-mysql-slave-from-a-running-master/) article where it says:

> The naive approach is just to use mysqldump to export a copy of the
>   master and load it on the slave server. This works if you only have
>   one database. With multiple database, you'll end up with inconsistent
>   data. Mysqldump will dump data from each database on the server in a
>   different transaction. That means that your export will have data from
>   a different point in time for each database.

Thank you

Comment: What values did you use for `MASTER_LOG_POS` and `MASTER_LOG_FILE`?

Comment: Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM or both or something else?

Comment: I used the values from mysql dump provided by option --master-data=2. I use mostly InnoDB however there is one Wordpress installation that probably use MyISAM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're using (specifically the `--master-data=2` option) should be enough to get you a consistent dump, since `--master-data` implies `--lock-all-tables` (and the resulting offences against database performance that are implied).  The caveats specified in the `mysqldump`(1) manpage for the `--lock-all-tables` option should be observed.

I would suggest that the article you cite was either written prior to the availability of `--lock-all-tables` (or it's implicit activation with `--master-data`) or was written by someone incapable or unwilling to read documentation.  You may wish to query the author to determine which is the case.